# How drawing on mobile use [Konvajs]

Tags: konvajs

I see this demo https://konvajs.github.io/docs/sandbox/Free_Drawing.html

I have been able to draw on successful web desktop, but can not draw on mobile

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

KonvaJs comes with [mobile events](https://konvajs.github.io/docs/events/Mobile_Events.html) to provide support for mobile devices. All you need to do is to listen to those events as well. I have changed the events to `touchend`, `touchstart` & `touchmove`. So now it will work on mobile. Here's the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/zYd0oWSmajO2xvprEfGj?p=preview).

```
stage.on('contentTouchstart.proto', () =>{});
stage.on('contentTouchmove.proto', () =>{});
stage.on('contentTouchend.proto', () =>{});
```

**Note**: If you want to provide support for both you need to set listners for both.

Hope it helps.